# Setting input to QWebElement

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I have a HTML page with `<input type=file>`

I'm using QtWebkit and I'm already able to get the QWebElement of the INPUT type.

How do I set its value to a specific string (file path) so I can submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

A naive thing to do would be to set the `value` attribute of the `input` element.

```
element->setAttribute("value", "path");
```

This is will not work, though, since you're not allowed to set this attribute unless you're "the browser".

Probably the way to go is to use the [`mozSetFileNameArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.mozSetFileNameArray), like so:

```
const QString filePath = "/foo/bar/baz"; // or "C:\foo\bar\baz"
const QString js = QString(
    "var fileArray = {'%1'};"
    "this.mozSetFileNameArray(fileArray, fileArray.length);"
    ).arg(filePath);
element->evaluateJavaScript(js);
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. Setting the " value" attribute didn't work. I got around the problem using QNetworkAccessManager post method.

Comment: Did you check the mozSetFileNameArray way of doing it? That one should work.